# MySQL Select Additional Rows on Same Table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return "parent" notes, where the from_person_id = 2. I would also like to return all of the "parent" note's child rows.

- A "parent" note has a parent_note_id of 0.
- A "child" note has a parent_note_id equal to its "parent" note's thread_note_id.
- Both "parent" and "child" notes have the same thread_note_id.

Below is an example of 4 rows from the notes table. My query should be returning all 4 of these notes. Instead, it is only returning one.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM notes WHERE note_id <= 4;
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| note_id | parent_note_id | thread_note_id | from_person_id |
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       1 |              0 |              1 |              2 |
|       2 |              1 |              1 |              5 |
|       3 |              1 |              1 |              5 |
|       4 |              1 |              1 |              5 |
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DISTINCT n.*
    -> FROM notes as n
    -> JOIN notes as n2 on n2.thread_note_id = n.thread_note_id
    -> WHERE n.from_person_id = 2
    -> AND n.parent_note_id = 0;
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| note_id | parent_note_id | thread_note_id | from_person_id |
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       1 |              0 |              1 |              2 |
+---------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I figured out a way to do it with two sub queries, but I am trying to avoid using sub queries in MySQL.

Anyone have a recommendation on how to get the query to return the parent note and all of its children using JOINs instead of Sub Queries?

Comment: Why can you not just return all rows with the same `thread_note_id`? It appears to me that this should match your desired result.

Comment: I only want the notes, where the "parent" note has a from_person_id of 2. I am not able to think of a way to get the children, since they have different from_person_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would do this as:

```
select n.*
from notes n
where n.parent_note_id = (select n2.note_id
                          from notes n2
                          where n2.from_person_id = 2
                         ) or
      n.from_person_id = 2;
```

For best performance, you want an index on `notes(from_person_id, note_id)`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, that is similar to what I found. But it uses a sub query, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Daryl . . . There is no reason to avoid a subquery.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...I've been instructed not to use sub queries on large tables in my work place. The reason I was given: Sub queries in MySQL do a Full Table Scan and on a large table that can make the query take a very long time.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: @Daryl . . . That is simply incorrect.  This subquery, for instance, will look up each value using the index.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...Thank you for your input. I very much appreciate it.